# Javascript Error: cyclic __proto__ value

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit

I want to change default window.location setter and getter functions.

The following code are successfully works. But This codes are only work limited area.

```
var _window = window;
(function () {
    window = {}; 
    var window = {}; 

    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      get: function () { alert('called getter '); return _window.location; },
      set: function () { alert('not in my house'); }
    }); 

    window.__proto__ = _window;
    alert('window.location : '+ window.location);
}());
```

When I remove the block,

```
var _window = window;
window = {}; 
var window = {}; 

Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
  get: function () { alert('called getter '); return _window.location; },
  set: function () { alert('not in my house'); }
}); 

window.__proto__ = _window;
alert('window.location : '+ window.location);
```

I met the following error.

```
ERROR Error: cyclic __proto__ value
```

I know that can't redefine non-configurable property "location" in normal environment. I have changed binding IDL properties to test these code in webkit library. How can I solve this problem?

---

I have another question. When I run the following codes, I met the same error.(jsc - Javascript Core, Spidermonkey, nodejs)

```
var o1 = { p1: 1 };
var o2 = { p2: 2 };
o2.__proto__ = o1; 

var o3 = { p3: 3 };
o3.__proto__ = o2; 
o1.__proto__ = o3;
```

JavascriptCore shell(jsc)

```
Exception: Error: cyclic __proto__ value
```

node.js (v0.10.25)

```
Error: Cyclic __proto__ value
```

Spidermonkey JavaScript-C24.2.0

```
1.js:7:0 TypeError: cyclic __proto__ value
```

Is it related? Thank you ^^

Comment: Do not manipulate `__proto__`

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. My main purpose this is to detect changing window.location or inject some codes in the setter. Do you have any idea or methods? Object.observe and Object.watch are not support yet in webkit environment. But I can change DOM object to be configurable or replaceable.

Comment: Search for javascript injection or take a look at the source of AOP libs, how the original objects can be wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really create a prototype chain loop in both cases.
In the closure the `window` is the local variable (because of hoisting), therefore you do not create a prototype loop on global window object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var o1 = { p1: 1 };
 var o2 = { p2: 2 };
 var o3 = { p3: 3 };

 o2.__proto__ = o1; 
 o1.__proto__ = o3;
 o3.__proto__ = o2; 

VM432:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cyclic __proto__ value
at Object.set __proto__ [as __proto__] (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:7:14
```

**Reason:** JavaScript will throw an error if we try to assign `__proto__` in a circle.The references can’t go in circles.